# Is there a way to add a window list on the panel in Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, indicator

Is there a way in Natty with the Unity shell to add a Window List (or, even better, something like Talika) to the top bar?  Or, failing that, some sort of appindicator for open windows?

Ultimately, I'd like to replace the current global menu with a separate window list and a global menu that only shows the menu and never the window title, which I find distracting and duplicative.  That doesn't seem to be an option at this stage so I'm setting my sights on just adding a window list that allows me to see what I have open without any mouse or keyboard actions.

Comment: check the answer made by Marco: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity It adds a gnome panel so you -can-. Looks ugly though ;)

Comment: @JacobVlijm has done something like this before http://askubuntu.com/a/569481/295286

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple script using `wmctrl` and a tool I made to create appindicators:

https://sites.google.com/site/redaea/cappind-py/examples/windowlist

it requires `wmctrl` (`apt-get` it) and this tool => https://sites.google.com/site/redaea/cappind-py/

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing that I'm aware of. Are you a programmer? You could hack together a python script around **wmctrl** and export the window list as an Indicator. You could ask some a friend, someone on IRC or request OMGUbuntu to publish a request for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this (add a window list). Open a terminal and type in 'gnome-panel' and hit enter.  A panel should appear at the bottom. I unchecked 'expand' option and removed the trash can icon.  My bottom panel has 'show desktop icon', 'window list', and 'workplace switcher' which I changed to two, instead of four.  You will notice that your top panel has changed and you now have a window bar and you can add more now to that panel.  Hope this helps.  If you close the terminal, your panels will dissapear.  To fix this, open 'startup applications' and add to the list of application you want to start after a reboot. Click 'add' button on the right and enter 'gnome panel,gnome-panel,start gnome panel' in the three boxes, respectively. ;)